# Oracle Enterprise Manager read-only access for non-administrative users

Tags: oracle, enterprise-manager

Can access to OEM be restricted to the point where you can allow a non-admin user access to it but they can't modify any objects but can still view performance data, alerts, sessions, etc? I am a former DBA now developer and I don't have an environment where I can go verify this myself.

Answer (score 1):

You allow a non-admin user access to the Performance area of OEM by granting them the `OEM_MONITOR` role. However, be aware that this role does have a few additional priviliges that you may not want to provide. In that case I would create a similar role to `OEM_MONITOR` but with a reduced set of privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just create the user with the `PUBLIC` role, then grant them `VIEW ANY TARGET`.

Comment: I'd have thought that for the tasks requested (view perf data etc) they'd also need appropriately privileged database users on the targets they have access to, strictly I suspect these wouldn't count as read-only users.